# color picker in custom webpart properties

Tags: development, custom-web-part-property

I want to have custom color picker in web part properties to let users select colors for headings. Any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Any one has any idea ??

Comment: The controls on web part properties are limited, you can only create simple controls like textbox, dropdowns, checkbox and buttons (I don't know if I miss another one)...   So, I think you can make a simple color picker with dropdown controls... let me know if you need assistance on how to create these controls, but I would need to know the SP version and VS version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What you suggest is to have simple color names in drop-down and then get color from its hex code through script ..right.! But I want to let users select proper color from color picker.! that will be more easy for us to choose colors more precisely.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any idea for this case. greatly appreciated. I'll let you know my questions if I need in this case if we decide to move along with usual controls like drop-downs and all. thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to **replicate a simple color picker** with a dropdown control setting the corresponding background color foreach item. This way you can get the following:

[image]

Maybe this could be a good solution for your requirement.

**Useful information:**

*How to create a custom web part editor:*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh228018(v=office.14).aspx

*How to build a Color DropDownList control*
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19356/Multi-color-DropDownList-using-C

Comment: oh..that's great.it will help me out for sure.I appreciate. thank you very much